# JavaScript Проблема с кодировкой файла PDF

Tags: javascript, кодировка, pdf

Помогите решить проблему с кодировкой для экспорта данных в формате PDF. Вместо русских слов выводит непонятные символы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
<?php $this->registerJsFile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js') ?>
<?php $this->registerJsFile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.4.3/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js') ?>

<?php $this->registerJs('
$("#btnExport2").click(function(e){
    var doc = new jsPDF("portrait", "pt", "a4", true)
    doc.autoTable({ html: "#table" })
    doc.save("Отчет.pdf")
    e.preventDefault();
});
')?>
```

Изменил код на:

```
$("#btnExport2").click(function(e){
    var doc = new jsPDF("portrait", "pt", "a4", true);
    var data_table = $("#table")[0].outerHTML;
    var data = "data:application/pdf," + "\uFEFF" + encodeURIComponent(data_table);
    doc.autoTable({ html: data});
    doc.save("Звіт.pdf");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Все равно ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, но почему-то теряется качество

```
$("#btnExport4").click(function(e){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("table"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Table.pdf");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь же качество лучше, но не распознает кириллицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может проблема в версии jsPDF?

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.1/jspdf.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.4.3/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js

Comment: Спасибо, Юра, что ответил на мой вопрос, но мириться с плохим качеством я не буду.